# Access multiple fields from Selector (when using Provider state management in Flutter)?

Tags: flutter, dart, selector, provider

I have a task manager app that displays a number of TaskWidget widgets in a ListView and am currently trying to modify my app to use Provider for state management. I have a TaskListModel class as my ChangeNotifier that contains a List of TaskModel along with some getters and setters that call notifyListeners(). (TaskModel is not a ChangeNotifier)

When the user modifies data for a single task in the list, I want to rebuild that widget without rebuilding all the other widgets in the list. Selector almost does what I want, except that I need to access all the fields in TaskModel to rebuild the corresponding TaskWidget, whereas Selector only seems to work with a single field. I've tried using Selector by setting the selector to an instance of TaskModel using the list index. I assume this doesn't work because it is listening to the reference of TaskModel (which doesn't change) rather than all the fields within TaskModel. Is there a straightforward way for me to do this? I've included the build method for TaskWidget below for reference.

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Column(children: <Widget>[
  Selector<TaskListModel, TaskModel>(
    selector: (_, taskListModel) => taskListModel.taskList[index],
    builder: (_, taskModel, child) {
      print("rebuilding " + index.toString());

      return Material(
        color: taskModel.color,
        child: ListTile(
          title: Column(children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              taskModel.name,
              style: _taskFont,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
            Text(
              taskModel.formattedTime,
              style: _taskFont,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
          ]),
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
  Divider(
    height: 0.0,
  ),
]);

  }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As stated by [the documentation of Selector](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/Selector-class.html), you should either make a custom class or use the package `tuple`.

> To select multiple values without having to write a class that implements ==, the easiest solution is to use a "Tuple" from tuple:
>
> ```dart
> Selector<Foo, Tuple2<Bar, Baz>>(
>   selector: (_, foo) => Tuple2(foo.bar, foo.baz),
>   builder: (_, data, __) {
>     return Text('${data.item1}  ${data.item2}');
>   }
> )
> ```

Comment: Could you elaborate further on this? I am stuck with the same problem, and I have used tuple to compare between fields in an object. But I am confused when I want to use the same approach to compare two objects. 

If I have a List<User> _users, and I want to rebuild every time I add to the list or rebuild a ListTile when I change one of the objects in the list, how do I go about doing this?